# How can I download specific versions of plugins in IONIC?

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to use the BarcodeScanner plugin in the Ionic v3 project, but it's giving an error:

> Object (...) is not a function

when I click a button with the simple `BarcodeScanner.scan()` function. So I searched for a long time the reason for this to happen, I saw N videos of how I can use this plugin and all these attempts failed. So as a last resort I created a blank Ionic 4 project and used the BarcodeScanner plugin in the same way as the other project and it worked. 
   So I need/want to download this plugin in a older version to be compatible with the version of my project. Currently the plugin is in its v8.0.1 version and I want to install v7.1.2.
Please, help me!

Comment: What is your `@ionic-native/barcode-scanner` version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this add version with @

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@7.1.2
```

i hope it help :)

Answer (score 1):

It is like npm with modules. U use `@latest` or `@7.1.2`(@7.1.2 is the version)

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@7.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely your Barcode Scanner Ionic Native version rather than the cordova plugin itself.

Since Ionic Framework 4 was released, Installing Ionic Native for all Cordova plugins in Ionic Framework 3 requires adding `@4` to get the latest Ionic 3 compatible version. So, for the barcode scanner plugin, you have to install it's Ionic Native using `@ionic-native/barcode-scanner@4`. This should fix the issues you are having.